# Why value doesn't want to increment when I submit a post

Tags: php, forms, session

I'm making a login attempt checker, so if user inputs wrong key (witch was send via email) then It add +1 on the attempt meter. I stored it in a session did quite a lot of research but it just doesn't work. here is my PHP code.

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['poskusi'] = 0;
$kljuc = $_SESSION['rand_kljuc'];

if(isset($_POST['vpis_kljuc'])){
  $vpis_kljuc = $_POST['vpis_kljuc'];
  if($vpis_kljuc == $kljuc){
    echo "You are in";
  }
  else {
    echo "Wrong key";
    $_SESSION['poskusi']+1;
    if($_SESSION['poskusi'] == 3){
      echo "locked";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);` anything from this?

Comment: `$_SESSION['poskusi']+1;` should be `$_SESSION['poskusi']+=1;`

Comment: `$_SESSION['poskusi']+1` should be `$_SESSION['poskusi'] += 1;` or `$_SESSION['poskusi']++;`

Comment: Also, you're setting `$_SESSION['poskusi']` to `0` every time the PHP script is loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the counter to `0` every time the page loads.

Try this:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['poskusi'])) {
    $_SESSION['poskusi'] = 0;
}
```

You are also incrementing it wrong. It should be

`$_SESSION['poskusi']++;` or

`$_SESSION['poskusi']+=1;` if you prefer.

Comment: code doesn't work for me I added session_destroy() and then just redirect it to login

Comment: Well now it increment nicely but when I add function above it doesn't set $_SESSION['poskusi'] to 0 but it just keep going

Comment: That's because the variable is already set. When do you want it to be set to 0?

Comment: After 3 tries then client will have to wait idk 5-10 min then I'll set $_SESSION['poskusi'] to 0

Comment: @ribicem Ok so under your `echo "locked";`, add your logic for waiting 5-10 minutes and set the counter back to 0. You will need to close your browser to get the counter to start at 0 again.

Comment: I think I fixed it thanks's for patience and help  :)